# Generate client proxy from endpoint address WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Is it possible for a WCF Service with two endpoints to provide a way, for the client, to generate his proxies from a specific endpoint ? I'm currently using the "Add Service Reference" feature from VS 2013 and it will obtain all classes defined by two contracts.

My two contracts define differents request/response. IServiceTCP provide admin-like methods and in IServiceHttp user-like methods.

Since I got a client who will only communicate in HTTP and he's not in the same network (making the endpoint in tcp useless), I would like to provide him a way to generate his proxies getting only classes needed from the http contract.

It seems I can provide an address to the endpoint that will be appended to the base address of the service. Since I'm hosted behind an IIS server, if I give the address "testhttp" to my endpoint, it would be resolved as "http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc/testhttp". I didn't found a way for a client to consume that address.

```
 <service name="Namespace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorA">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingHttp" contract="Namespace.IServiceHttp"  />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingTCP" contract="Namespace.IServiceTCP" />
  </service>
```

I would like to avoid creating two services to achieve this purpose.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this can be achieved without creating two services. If you're trying to create two endpoints, this is what you should try:
Give the two endpoints different service name:

```
<service name="Namespace.ServiceA" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorA">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingHttp" contract="Namespace.IServiceHttp"  />
</service>

 <service name="Namespace.ServiceB" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorA">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingTCP" contract="Namespace.IServiceTCP" />
</service>

<serviceHostingEnvironment >
            <serviceActivations>
                <add relativeAddress="ServiceA.svc" service="Namespace.ServiceA" />
                <add relativeAddress="ServiceB.svc" service="Namespace.ServiceB" />
</serviceActivations>/serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Now the two endpoints should be accessible via

1. http://localhost/MyService/ServiceA.svc
2. http://localhost/MyService/ServiceB.svc

HTH.

Comment: Since service name must be resolved as a class, it imply that I must create two classes of service. (ServiceA and ServiceB). It would be more logical, with two services, to completly separate them with differents URL at this point. Thanks for your time.